# Is there a way to inherit parameters from a parent class's constructor?

Tags: typescript, constructor, super

The problem I'm having is that I have some base (generic) classes whose properties are initialized via the class's constructor. When I then go to extend this class to create a more specific class, I must re-type the same parameters that the base class's constructor has, just so I can pass them to super. If you imagine a very generic class that has many properties that are initialized via a constructor , and that is extended quite often, having to constantly re-type all these properties just to pass them to super each time seems inefficient. I am likely missing some common way of preventing this. Any ideas how to make this more efficient? Perhaps by somehow "inheriting" the parent class's constructor parameters?

Here's a code example, and, as you can see, in `Programmer`'s constructor, I have to re-type `name`, `age`, and `height` again just to pass it to `super`:

```js
class Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    height: number;

    constructor(name: string, age: number, height: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
    }
}

class Programmer extends Person {
    languages: string[];

    constructor(name: string, age: number, height: number, languages: string[]) {
        super(name, age, height);

        this.languages = languages;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have default value for those parameter in case of it's is optional fields for instantiate Programmer instance.

Comment: A programmer is a person so he has name,age, other fields so it suppose to be initialized when you creating the class. Make what is optional and create instance of programmer based on whats is necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't inherit, but you can refer to the parameter using `ContructorParameters` and you can spread them back in your derived constructor, as long as you don't mind adding any new parameters at the front:

```
class Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    height: number;

    constructor(name: string, age: number, height: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
    }
}

class Programmer extends Person {
    languages: string[];

    constructor(languages: string[], ...p: ConstructorParameters<typeof Person>) {
        super(...p);

        this.languages = languages;
    }
}

new Programmer(["A"], "", 1, 1) // Since 3.4 you will get actual parameter names in intelisense not just ...p
```

Not sure it's the best design though, and if you have a lot of parameters you might be better off defining an interface and passing that in instead. Or using some sort of mapped type to extract relevant fields.

Comment: Thanks, this is quite useful :)

Comment: In case anyone from the future is curious, you can sum up the solution to my problem with the phrase "rest parameters".

Comment: Can't edit previous comment, but I should have said "spread operator" and not "rest parameters".

Answer (score 1):

As `Person` is base class which can not be initialize without `name`, `age` and `height`, the extended class `Programmer` will compulsory needs the same constructor args.

As you have mentioned in case there are many arguments, you can use creation pattern (like builder pattern) to create object of extended class.

If you want no arg constructor you can make super constructor parameter as optional.

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  height: number;

  constructor(name?: string, age?: number, height?: number) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.height = height;
  }
}


class Programmer extends Person {
  languages: string[];

  constructor(languages: string[]) {
      super();

      this.languages = languages;
  }
}
```

Comment: How is that supposed to work, especially with `this.languages = languages;` ?