# Proper way to type rest parameters within named parameters class extends constructor in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I have a class with few parameters, that are initialized in the class constructor, and then I have a second class that `extends` the former. For instance (the number of parameters is actually much bigger):

```
class MyClass {
  name?: string;
  day?: Date;

  constructor({
    name,
    day,
  }: { name?: string, day?: Date } = {}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.day = day;
  }
}

class MyAwesomeClass extends MyClass {
  isAwesome?: boolean;

  constructor({
    isAwesome,
    ...props
  }: { isAwesome?: boolean } = {}) {
    super(props)
    this.isAwesome = isAwesome
  }
}
```

The problem with the above is that I am not specifying the type of `props` and, altough I am not getting a compiling error, I am not able to exploit coding suggestions and it is much more error prone.

```
const awesome = new MyAwesomeClass({ isAwesome: true, name: "test" })
// 'name' does not exist in type '{ isAwesome?: boolean | undefined; }'
```

What is the proper way to handle it? I may re-write all the parameters, but since I have plenty of them it is again very error prone, as I may miss a couple without noticing.

BTW, if your solution also helps with original `MyClass`, i.e. automatically extracting parameters instead of needing to rewrite them all, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

One way is just to extract the props as a type, and then you can union the props on the inherited.

eg.

```
type MyClassProps = { name?: string, day?: Date };

class MyClass {
  name?: string;
  day?: Date;

  constructor({
    name,
    day,
  }: MyClassProps = {}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.day = day;
  }
}

type MyAwesomeClassProps = MyClassProps & {isAwesome?: boolean}

class MyAwesomeClass extends MyClass {
  isAwesome?: boolean;

  constructor({
    isAwesome,
    ...props
  }: MyAwesomeClassProps = {}) {
    super(props)
    this.isAwesome = isAwesome
  }
}

const c = new MyAwesomeClass({isAwesome:true, name:'Bob'});
```

Working example
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsmAwgGwIYGd0AUBOB7CdGAXhgG8YA7VAWygH4AuGdEHAS0oHMAaGAE1RgmMACKoQsAL4BuYMADGaTPCTKiZYDCq0GzVh25ztg4c3GS5WmAryUDAVwUg8OABSbt26nR7WTQn7aUswIKBjY%20IQk5FIAlOT%20MCAAFuzoAHQ%20sKTZxl6p6RmmMab5UsAVoJCwCACCAO5Q6Hh04Zi4BESkYeqd0QBk5OmNza16MABGeHjIUKiUVUoRqqMtbeowUAAekpT8RL0rnjAjTesT07PzlFbatvZsTi7uJ9pnY75JGT8QUejWEKrc7jdqRLoxMjxRJeFgOaDuP5dOJJQqZD4XGIY8aAyryB6sGwxShQBrAz5QMEebF0RhPKB8bKMADkACE8JNmfEZEA)

If you wish copy the type from the Constructor, you can do -> [Is there a way to inherit parameters from a parent class's constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353764/is-there-a-way-to-inherit-parameters-from-a-parent-classs-constructor)  But personally I think that looks more complicated than just extracting the Types..

And if using `ConstructorParameters` ->
[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=38&pln=20&pc=59#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oDswFsBTAfgC5oIAXAJwEscBzAbi2gBMx4zoARMSwi1bAA9jirUArsEojqACkzZseIgBpW2DvA3YAvuTS4CJchPoM17Ttz4Doe6AF50egJTpN0SgAtaEADpVQmdjIhZlbz9A7VDtCIcMPQwMUEgYBABBAHdCCBEiZHToQgAPARw2DKQUGCVofxy8gtNoACMRERBCMBwhbFFxGmlZBXrsRtz89S8AuYAHahF5iFYDdEnmom4Orp6cRwAyaABRUtBJNkIAHkQxCRG5AAUwahMBaghrynh5whEAGZwGrpAB8AG0AAwAXSskkqhAB9EIbFBoTQ7k8kQgkj%20CkWywgbi8vn8AU20xCLgpLTWSRSgyo0GAoRwhGywKalKKUEUNKIpGGhCswVIAHIAEIiNpi9xMIA)

I'll leave for others to decide what is the easiest to implement / understand..

Comment: Note: you may use `NonNullable` or `& {}` as an alternative to `Exclude<_, undefined>`. As you have `{isAvesome: boolean} & _` you don't really need it.

Comment: @Dimava  Yeah, I did wonder if there was some cleaner way.  That's why I said `one way`.  The helper Type your created looks nice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a helper type to let you do that:
https://tsplay.dev/WvyDMm

```
type Pure<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } & unknown
type ExtendsParameters<C extends abstract new (...args: any) => any, P> = Pure<P & NonNullable<ConstructorParameters<C>[0]>>

type x = ExtendsParameters<typeof MyClass, { isAwesome?: boolean }>
// type x = {
//     isAwesome?: boolean | undefined;
//     name?: string | undefined;
//     day?: Date | undefined;
// }

class MyAwesomeClass extends MyClass {
  isAwesome?: boolean;

  constructor({
    isAwesome,
    ...props
  }: ExtendsParameters<typeof MyClass, { isAwesome?: boolean }> = {}) {
    super(props)
    this.isAwesome = isAwesome
  }
}
```

It is possible to extend this for multiple arguments.
If all of the class properties are its constructor parameters this may be simplified