# Modifying a parent class's constructor parameters and passing them to `super()`

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types, parameters

I have a base class, `Sprite`, and a subclass `Player`. `Sprite`'s `constructor()` takes a few parameters, one of which is the path to an image. `Player` should take all parameters except the image path, and should take a new parameter which it will use to determine the image path itself.

The question [Is there a way to inherit parameters from a parent class's constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56353764/is-there-a-way-to-inherit-parameters-from-a-parent-classs-constructor) led me to `ConstructorParameters`:

```js
// Sprite.ts

import SomeVendoredRenderLibrary from "./vendored/SomeVendoredRenderLibrary.js";

export default abstract class Sprite {
  private _image: HTMLImageElement;

  public constructor(
    protected canvasWidth: number,
    protected canvasHeight: number,
    imagePath: string
  ) {
    this._image = SomeVendoredRenderLibrary.loadImage(imagePath);
  }
}
```

```js
// Player.ts

import Sprite from "./Sprite.js";

export default class Player extends Sprite {
  constructor(
    type: "modelA" | "modelB",
    ...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Sprite>
  ) {
    // this doesn't work! 
    args.imagePath = `assets/player_${type}.png`;
    super(...args);
  }
}
```

Of course, the above code fails because `args` is an array and hence can't be assigned by name. Furthermore, `ConstructorParameters<typeof Sprite>` requires `imagePath` to be passed explicitly, although it would be redundant.

It would of course be possible to explicitly add each required parameter of `Sprite` to `Player` and its other subclasses, as parameters to `constructor()` and arguments to `super()`, but this seems like a hacky workaround, as it would require manually updating all subclasses should any changes be made to `Sprite`.

What's the canonical way to inherit/passthrough `constructor()` parameters from a parent class, while potentially modifying some?

Comment: are you aware that `args` is an array and therefore `args.imagePath` does not work but `args[2]` was the right way to refer the `imagePath` parameter?

Comment: @PeterSeliger yes, I know it's an array, but if I were to add a parameter to `Sprite` that changes the position of `imagePath`, subclasses would be broken. i've edited my question to clarify that. i was hoping there would be a better way?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's `...args`, `args` or passing parameters directly to the function; as long as parameters are reflected as `arguments` array the problem of breaking subclasses when changing the `arguments`' signature does remain. The only way of preventing the latter is to make use of a single object based parameter which features all of the former parameters as its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above comments ...

> @PeterSeliger yes, I know it's an array, but if I were to add a parameter to `Sprite` that changes the position of `imagePath`, subclasses would be broken. i've edited my question to clarify that. i was hoping there would be a better way? – theo
>
> > It doesn't matter whether it's `...args`, `args` or passing parameters directly to the function; as long as parameters are reflected as `arguments` array the problem of breaking subclasses when changing the `arguments`' signature does remain. The only way of preventing the latter is to make use of a single object based parameter which features all of the former parameters as its properties. – Peter Seliger

One could do it by either [extending an already existing type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) ...

```
import SomeVendoredRenderLibrary from "./vendored/SomeVendoredRenderLibrary.js";

type PlayerOptions = {
  canvasWidth: number,
  canvasHeight: number,
};    
type SpriteOptions = PlayerOptions & {
  imagePath: string,
};

class Sprite {

  // ... modifier declaration

  constructor({ canvasWidth, canvasHeight, imagePath }:SpriteOptions) {

    // ... assignments
  }
}

class Player extends Sprite {
  constructor(
    type: "modelA" | "modelB",
    options: PlayerOptions,
  ) {
    super({ ...options, imagePath: `assets/player_${ type }.png`});
  }
}
```

... or by defining a single (meta) type for any constructor's single parameter and explicitly [omitting properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) as suggested by *Shalom Peles* ...

```
import SomeVendoredRenderLibrary from "./vendored/SomeVendoredRenderLibrary.js";

type SpriteOptions = {
  canvasWidth: number,
  canvasHeight: number,
  imagePath: string,
};

class Sprite {

  // ... modifier declaration

  constructor({ canvasWidth, canvasHeight, imagePath }:SpriteOptions) {

    // ... assignments
  }
}

class Player extends Sprite {
  constructor(
    type: "modelA" | "modelB",
    options: Omit<SpriteOptions, 'imagePath'>
  ) {
    super({ ...options, imagePath: `assets/player_${ type }.png`});
  }
}
```

Comment: You can improve it by using `options: Omit<SpriteOptionsType, 'imagePath'>` as the second argument of Player's constructor.
This way you shouldn't pass the redundant `imagePath` to the Player's constructor.

Comment: @ShalomPeles ... You are right, and there are even more ways of achieving it. I'llm update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I ended up using the second option from @ShalomPeles - thanks :)